# How to implement master/slave database configuration in Magento 2 community edition?

Tags: magento2, performance

As we know master/slave or split database configuration is possible with Magento 2 enterprise edition and not with the community edition.

How we can implement master/slave or split database functionality in community edition? Is there way/resource/tutorial which can help me to achieve this functionality?

Comment: There are many features which is only available with Enterprise edition and not with community edition. With help of third party tools/extensions or our own customization we can implement enterprise-only features in community edition. I believe this question also falls in the same category and I do not see it as a waste of time. If it was Magento 1 we could have used separate database for read and write operation by updating app/etc/local.xml . I am looking for a solution using which I can use separate db for read and write operation in Magento 2.

Answer (score 4):

You can get more details on how to configure master-slave in Magento 2 from skynix blog post

https://skynix.co/resources/magento-2-ce-database-replication

The source code of the solution is licensed as open source and available [here](https://bitbucket.skynix.co/projects/M2E/repos/magento-2---mysql-cluster/browse)

Comment: Looks like a good starting point Arshad. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is down.

Comment: @Gambo link is not down actually code what they had implemented is not supporting higher version of magento 2. You can get it from github and if u could debug its code u can surely help whole community.

Comment: Hope it helps you https://skynix.co/resources/magento-2-ce-database-replication

Comment: "UPDATE: We’re sad to inform that this module is not supported by the latest versions of Magento and requires an upgrade." + they took the github repo down.

Answer (score -2):

You can check this documentation:

**This feature is available in Magento Commerce only.**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master_manual.html

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question I know this is in-built feature on enterprise edition. I am looking for a solution how we can customise it for community edition.